# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, ssl, ca

Since downloading the new version of Postgres (Version 16.1) I am unable to properly work with pip. Therefore, I am unable to install packages, resulting in the following error:

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt

I already tried to manually create a pip.ini file, in which I defined a path to my cacert.pem - fie. However, this did not change anything.

Any help on this issue or hints, where this might come from is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It says `Invalid path`:

Work around:

You can get the location of `certifi` by:

```
import certifi
certifi.where()
```

Keep this path of `cacert.pem` file handy.

---

You can get all the possible `pip.ini` files by running:

```
pip config -v list
```

---

Finally,

edit the `pip.ini` file and set the `path = <file_path_of_cacert.pem>`

Comment: Dear Goku, thank you very much for your response. I have one follow up question: When running: pip config -v list, I receive 4 possible locations (one marked as global, two as user and one as site). However, following these paths, in none of these 4 locations exists a pip.ini file. Can I manually add such a pip.ini file and if so, does it make a difference in which of those 4 locations?

Comment: You're welcome dear @pw_muc.. apologies I am not sure..Please give it a try and check.

Answer (score 1):

Delete **C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt** from System variables inside Environment variables worked for me

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me :

use `trusted-host` in either pip.conf or command line argument

You can ignore SSL errors by setting pypi.org and files.pythonhosted.org as well as the older pypi.python.org as trusted hosts.

```
$ pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package_name>
```

If you are still getting this error I suggest you review this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29751768/10004902